# need bottom of text in a menu to line up

Tags: html, css

I have a menu created like this:

```
    <div id="site-header-menu" class="site-header-menu">
  <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation" aria-label="Primary Menu">
    <div class="menu-main-menu-container">
      <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="primary-menu">
        <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="http://localhost/fairground/">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/fairground/about-us/">about us</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/fairground/our-products/">our products</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://localhost/fairground/shop/">shop</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- .main-navigation -->
</div>
<!-- .site-header-menu -->
```

When a link is active I need the font to be larger and I need all links to line up along the bottom of the text so the bottom of the large word 'home' lines up with the bottom of the next link and so on as in this image:

[image]

I can't seem to get this to work. I have tried various display:xxx for the li and the a, and various vertical-align properties but nothing seems to work

I have created a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/maxelcat/x2xmsa6a/3/)

Here's my css

```
.site-header-menu {
  background: rgba(244, 39, 58, 0.42);
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.main-navigation ul {
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin: 0;
}

.main-navigation a {
  color: red;
  font-size: 24px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: auto;
}

.main-navigation .primary-menu > li {
  display: table-cell;
  float: left;
  background: #ccc;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

.current-menu-item a {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure i understand correctly but like this?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var $items = $("#menu-main-menu > li");
  $items.on("click", function(){
    $items.removeClass("current-menu-item");
    $(this).addClass("current-menu-item");
  });
});
```

```css
.site-header-menu {
  background: rgba(244, 39, 58, 0.42);
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 40px;
}

.main-navigation ul {
  list-style: outside none none;
  margin: 0;
}

.main-navigation a {
  color: red;
  font-size: 24px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: auto;
}

.main-navigation .primary-menu > li {
  display: inline;
  background: #ccc;
}
.main-navigation .primary-menu > li:hover > a { font-size: 40px;color: black;}
.current-menu-item a {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="site-header-menu" class="site-header-menu">
  <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation" aria-label="Primary Menu">
    <div class="menu-main-menu-container">
      <ul id="menu-main-menu" class="primary-menu">
        <li class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">about us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">our products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">shop</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- .main-navigation -->


</div>
<!-- .site-header-menu -->
```

Comment: thanks for you help - but not exactly - I have added an image

Comment: ok, so, in the beginning `home` is with big font; then when you hover another link `that link` get bigger font and `home` smaller like the other inactive ones?

Comment: to be honest I was only going to make the size change for the active link. Hovering would just be the usual colour change

Comment: oh, then all you need to do is add and remove that `current-menu-item` class on `click` event

Comment: I've updated the answer - but if you have this same navbar html on every page all you need to do is put the `current-menu-item` on that `li` element which page corresponds to(like: if is `home.html` you do this: `<li class="current-menu-item"><a href="#">home</a></li>`)

Comment: thanks - I slightly adapted what you did and it works fine!